# Create a map where countries can be selected using react-leaflet

Tags: css, react.js, jsx, user-interface, leaflet

I've only just started learning javascript and decided to try and make a simple app where individual countries can be selected, highlighting them, and the name appearing in the top corner.

The code works, but there as a novice I'm sure its far from the best way to do it! One thing I feel isn't the best is using a global var for country selection (`window.selected`).

The main app MyMap.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L from "leaflet"
import {MapContainer, GeoJSON, useMap, useMapEvent } from "react-leaflet";
import mapData from './../data/countries.json';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

// Set default value for no selection
window.selected = '</b><i>Click a country</i><b>'

// Custom Components
let info = L.control();
info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this.div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this.div.innerHTML = '<h4>Current Selection</h4><i>Click a country</i><br />';
    return this.div;
};
info.update = function (props) {
    this.div.innerHTML = '<h4>Current Selection</h4><b>'+props+'</b><br />';
};

function InfoBox() {
    // Add to the map
    const map = useMap()
    info.addTo(map);

    // Update text to display selected country
    useMapEvent('click', () => {
        info.update(window.selected)
    })
    return null
  }

function TileLayer() {
    const map = useMap();
    const mapboxAccessToken = TOKEN_HERE;

    // Set default values for the map
    React.useEffect(() => {
      new L.TileLayer(
        "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=" + mapboxAccessToken,
        {
          tileSize: 512,
          zoomOffset: -1
        }
      ).addTo(map);
    }, [map]);

    return null;
  }


// Create Map
class MyMap extends Component {
    state = {selectedCountry: null}

    geoStyle = {
        stroke: false, 
        fillOpacity: 0
    };
    
    // Highlight the selected country
    highlightCountry = (e) => {
        if (this.state.selectedCountry ) {
            this.state.selectedCountry.setStyle(this.geoStyle);
        }
        info.update(this.state.selectedCountry)
        this.setState({ selectedCountry: e.target });
        window.selected = e.target.feature.properties.ADMIN
        var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
            stroke: true,
            weight: 3,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        layer.bringToFront();
    }

    onEachCountry = (country, layer) => {
        layer.on({
            click: this.highlightCountry
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 style={{textAlign: "center"}}>My Map</h1>
                <MapContainer style={{height: "80vh"}} zoom={2} center={[30, 0]}>
                    <GeoJSON style={this.geoStyle} data={mapData.features} onEachFeature={this.onEachCountry} />
                    <TileLayer />
                    <InfoBox />
                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyMap;
```

and the css:

```
.info {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.info h4 {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  color: #777;
}
.MapContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

The HTML is the generic react html doc from create-react-app.